# Are yearly user ranking percentages being calculated correctly?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, reputation-leagues

According to the [reputation league ranking](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2022-01-01/3357935#3357935), my account has a year rank of 3,103 on Stack Overflow:

[image: Stevoisiak's yearly rank 3103]

The top of the reputation league page states that Stack Overflow has a total of 18,113,362 users:

[image: Stack overflow total users]

A quick calculation indicates my account would be in the top 0.02% of users for the year. `(3,013/18,113,362 total users)`. However, the stats on my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357935/stevoisiak?tab=profile) claim my account is only in the top 0.59% of users for the year.

[image: profile page, top 0.59% this year]

**If my account is in the top 0.59% of 18,113,362 users, wouldn't my year rank be 106,868 instead of 3,103?**